# Azure ADAL:2.0.1-alpha:Id token expiry time is always set as default

Tags: android, adal, azure-ad-b2c, azure-active-directory

There is mismatch between the web response received by library and response expected by library.On executing acquireToken() following web response is received by library

```
{"not_before":"****", "token_type":"Bearer", "id_token":"****", "id_token_expires_in":"****", "profile_info":"****", "refresh_token":"****", "refresh_token_expires_in":"*****" }
```

While parsing the response ADAL looks for key 'idtoken_expires_in'

```
    if(mRequest.isIdTokenRequest()){
        expiresInLookUp = "idtoken_expires_in";
        token = response.get(AuthenticationConstants.OAuth2.ID_TOKEN);
    }

    String expires_in = response.get(expiresInLookUp);
```

Since the web response has the key 'id_token_expires_in' and while parsing the response library is looking for "idtoken_expires_in",it is unable to find the required key and setting the token expiry time as default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed in 2.0.2-alpha.